# install wikidpad

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, deb

How can I install WikiDPad? I know I have ran it before on ubuntu 14.10 and now I want to run it on 15.04. I have looked for .debs or a ppa for it but I don't know whether to trust the sources that I am getting from Google.

I don't know where or how I installed it the last time. can anyone tell me how to install it? I don't want to compile from source. all though I can I just don't want to deal with it. I prefer .debs or PPA's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PPA and the package is not available via the standard repositories.

By I think, you can trust [GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net/). From time to time the site is down, but otherwise there are no problems.

Install the GetDeb repository:

```
cd
wget http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -I getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Install WikidPad

```
sudo apt-get install wikidpad
```

Comment: I came accosted getdeb but I was not sure of I could trust them as I had never heard of them. I am very interested in the project as I would like the most up to date packages as I can.

Comment: I use it for years. From time to time the site is down, but otherwise there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-wikidpad-2-2-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-pinguy-os-and-elementary-os/

> Install WikidPad 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wikidpad
```